# Chrome 35 triggers popstate after back button was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, popstate

I know that there are many topics related to chrome and popstate event but after upgrading chrome to version 35 I encountered a new one.

This is the case:

I've got a listing page with categories and filters, after You choose category, page etc. content is reloaded via ajax and everything is handled by history API which works fine.

But when You go to detail page of item in listing - standard request, whole page is reloaded - then press back button on browser, You can see a listing page in position where You last clicked an item but then popstate is triggered (and I don't talk here about chrome popstate on initial page loads cause in version 34 popstate is no longer triggered on init), and because of code which I mentioned earlier to handle categories whole page is reloaded.

So the problem is that chrome 35 triggers popstate event after we press back button, and my question is:

**How to detect that this event is triggered after user came back from detail page to my listing page to not reloading this one.**

I try with document object referrer etc. but when it looks like solution on first time there was always the case when it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I've been running into this problem. My solution is a bit of a hack, but it seems to work pretty well otherwise. I've found that waiting 150ms before setting up my onpopstate handlers is enough to wait for Chrome to run its initial onpopstate handlers, which you can use to your "advantage". For instance, to detect if an initial onpopstate was run:

```
// wait for page to load
$(function() {
  var no_initial_onpopstate = true;
  var enabled = true;

  window.onpopstate = function() {
    if(!enabled) return;
    console.log("detected initial onpopstate");
    no_initial_onpopstate = false;
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    enabled = false;
    console.log("No initial onpopstate: ", no_initial_onpopstate);

    // no_initial_onpopstate indicates if the browser emitted an initial
    // onpopstate event. Do with that information what you will

    // 150ms delay seems to be the "magic number" to wait for Chrome to
    // run all of its initial onpopstate handlers (in my tests on localhost, at least)
  }, 150);
});
```

So, from this I gather that setting up your `onpopstate' callbacks after 150ms of the browser's DOM ready event will skip chrome's initial onpopstate.